# No HDMI output with ati 5470

Tags: 12.10, ati, hdmi, fglrx

My laptop is HP 3030ej with ATI 5470 and switchable graphics.

For some reason ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit, if that matters) doesn't recognize the HDMI output for my monitor. I tried following several tutorials for installing either the propitiatory drivers through amd's site, or just enabling the proprietary drivers through software sources. Nothing seems to work, I either end up with no unity, or with low graphics mode.

Does anyone have any idea what to do next?

Comment: Can you disable the switchable graphics and just run the ATI Chip via bios?
On my laptop I can only install fglrx when switchable graphics are disabled, if not I get a black screen and nothing happens.

Comment: Updated the bios to the latest version just now, no option to disable switchable graphics.

Answer (score -1):

I am user of ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

I will give the solution.

When I plug the hdmi cable from my laptop to my led tv the screen is black.

When I press the keys Fn+F4 i have the screen on my laptop and my tv too.

Look you don't have to install ati x.org drivers. I have installed the flgrx drivers.

The only thing is to install the pulseaudio.

Open the pulseaudio

You can check pcm ac3 mpeg and two other options.

Finally if you want to hear from your tv the sound you change the first the alsa mixer 
to cedar hdmi output.

That's it.

Now enjoy from your hdmi laptop screen and sound from your tv.